# hetzner ubuntu minimal vs nextcloud

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, nextcloud

What are the differences between 
[image: these ubuntu images] in the hetzer installation process?

I understand hwe ( https://askubuntu.com/questions/248914/what-is-hardware-enablement-hwe ), but not minimal vs nextcloud.

Also seen on their wiki https://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/Standardimages/en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `minimal` image comes with a minimal set of already installed applications and the `nextcloud` image has nextcloud and therefor dependencies like webserver and `PHP` already installed.

You posted a link to their wiki 
https://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/Standardimages/en which states the `LAMP images contain "Linux, Apache, MySQL and PHP"`. Maybe also have a look at
https://github.com/hetzneronline/installimage/blob/master/nextcloud.functions.sh which proves their is a nextcloud instance to be configured by the `installimage` script inside every `nextcloud` and `nextcloud-beta` image.

Comment: Guesses sometimes are useful as comments but seldom make good answers.

Comment: Can you offer any sources to confirm your answer?

Comment: Ok, I won't write "guess" in future answers if I'm pretty sure about it.

Comment: I guessed as much and went with the `minimal`. Thanks for digging :)